# What is the difference between the respective toString methods for POJO and POGO after mixing a groovy class

Tags: java, groovy, pojo, pogo

```
class A { String methodFromA() { 'A' } }
class B { String methodFromB() { 'B' } }
A.metaClass.mixin B
def o = new A()
assert o.methodFromA() == 'A'
assert o.methodFromB() == 'B'
assert o instanceof A
assert !(o instanceof B)

println A
println A.toString()


JavaPojo.metaClass.mixin( B)
def javaPojo=new JavaPojo()
println javaPojo
println javaPojo.toString()
```

result:

```
class com.xxx.A
class com.xxx.B
toString from Java
com.xxx.B@5c1a1ff9
```

why line3 is from java?
why line4 is a  intance toString (end with hashcode)

here is my env

➜  ~ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.7.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X

➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I steer clear of runtime metaprogramming, but my guess would be that since you're mixing in *an actual class* instead of a trait, every method in `B` gets applied to `JavaPojo`--and that happens to include a `toString()`.

Comment: Also, `mixin` is defined *on `Class`*, not on `MetaClass`. By grabbing the `metaclass` property, you may not be modifying the target you intend.